# C++: "specializing" a member function template to work for derived classes from a certain base class

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I have a base class `MessageBase`, from which I derive various other message classes, e.g., `MessageDerived`.  I have another class that does some processing on various types of data, including a catchall method template:

```
struct Process {
  void f(int a);
  void f(const char* b);
  template<typename T> void f(const T &t) { ... }
};
```

So if I call `Process::f` on a message object, the template method is called.

Now I want to add custom functionality for for my message classes.  I am not allowed to change `Process`, so I want to derive from it (but even if I could change it, I can't find a way to get the custom functionality). I tried:

```
struct ProcessDerived : public Process {
  void f(const MesaageBase& m) { ... }  // Custom functionality for messages.
};
```

But that only works when I call `ProcessDerived::f` on a `MessageBase` object.  If I invoke it on a `MessageDerived` object, the template method gets selected instead.

Is there a way to get the custom function selected on all message classes while letting the template catch all other types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SFINAE here. Here is an example (note that it needs c++11 to work):

```
struct ProcessDerived : public Process
{
  template<typename T> void f(const T &t, typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<MessageBase, T>::value, int, void>::type = 0)
  {
    /// do something specific
  }

  template<typename T> void f(const T &t, ...)
  {
    return Process::f (t);
  }
};
```

};

You can read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

Answer (score 0):

ProcessDerived::f shadows all definitions of Process::f (see here: [Overloading rules for inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939161/overloading-rules-for-inheritance-in-c)). So calling ProcessDerived::f with a MessageDerived object calls ProcessDerived::f(const MessageBase&) as this is the only visible f, but e.g.

```
ProcessDerived pd; 
pd(42);
```

won't compile. You need to add a

```
using Process::f;
```

in ProcessDerived for the problem you described showing up. The solution proposed by Alex Telishev while I was writing fixes both problems at once, however.